# Getting EditableText from EditText in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've recycler view with 0 items, I've added an option to manually add the items, my stracture is simple :

1. RV_Item.xml (contains EditText).
2. MyItem, which is an Object for RV ( contains private String Text; ).
3. MainActivity.java, where the stuff happen.

   ```
   // My List<Object>
   List<MyItem> Items = new ArrayList<>();

   // For Adding, I've added FAB-Button, When Clicked, it does the following :
   Items.add(new MyItem());
   CheckForEmptyItems();
   mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);

   Now, When the user click the save button, i want to take all the edittext in all the items he had added, i'm doing in the following way :

                   for(MyItem items : Items){
                       Log.i("PrintingInfo", items.getText() );
                   }
   ```

The problem is, i'm not getting the text he entered in all EditText fields, and it's returning Null in all of them, What's the issue in this ?

Comment: I know why i'm not getting the edittext, becuase i'm getting my Object string, what i want is a way to get the EditText inputed string.

Answer (score 1):

So, i don't know why always i know the answer after posting, but here's how you gonna know what the user typed :

in your Adapter Class, in onBindViewHolder method, add textlistener for the EditText, here's an example :

```
holder.MyEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            itemList.get(position).setText(s.toString());
        }
    });
```

Hope that helps you!